# Using Chrome And VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the below to open Chrome inside a VBA macro :

```
Shell ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe -url " & webURL)
```

where webURL is the website I want to open

This works fine but does anyone know how to manipulate the webpage once its open e.g. fill in the username box and click "Enter" etc

Cheers
Phil

Comment: Search for Chrome Selenium. Plenty of examples to get you started. if you get stuck, ask a question.

Comment: More specifically you want selenium-vba: https://code.google.com/archive/p/selenium-vba/

Comment: Or learn A LOT about websockets